# split log to separate rows redshift

Tags: sql, split, amazon-redshift

I want to create table that include rows created from log.
My log structure is

```
{"date":"..","by":..,"action":"..""argument":".."}, 
{"date":"..","by":..,"action":"..""argument":".."}, 
{"date":"..","by":..,"action":"..""argument":".."}
...
```

I need for every action X create new row with argument and date.

for example.
I have table:

```
id     log
1      {"date":"d1","by":..,"action":"x""argument":"y1"}, {"date":"d2","by":..,"action":"x""argument":"y2"}..
2      {"date":"d3","by":..,"action":"z""argument":"y1"}..
3      {"date":"d4","by":..,"action":"t""argument":"y3"}, {"date":"d5","by":..,"action":"x""argument":"y4"}
```

I need table like:

```
id     argument    date
1      y1          d1
1      y2          d2
3      y4          d5
```

the number of actions in the logs is changed.
My DB is **redshift and I am using Dbeaver.**

I saw query like this:

```
'SELECT ProductId, Name, value  
FROM Product  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tags, ',');  '
```

But its only for SQL server.

Any help? even with using functions. Thanks

Comment: Redshift is not really suited to this type of transformation.  It should be done when you load the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **json_extract_path_text** function on Amazon Redshift database

I prepared following SQL sample to demonstrate how to use json_extract_path_text

```
create table Logs (
id int, "log" varchar(max)
);

INSERT into Logs select 1, '{"date":"d1","by":"kodyaz.com","action":"x","argument":"y1"}';
INSERT into Logs select 2, '{"date":"d2","by":"eralper.com","action":"y","argument":"y2"}';

select 
    id,
    json_extract_path_text("log", 'argument') as "argument" ,
    json_extract_path_text("log", 'date') as "date" 
from Logs;
```

Output will be as you required

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. this is working great if I have only one section of {..}.
But if I have multiple like {..},{..},{...} it gives me error... can you help me with that?